# SQL query suddenly slowed to a crawl

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running a query on SQL Server based on a view. This view's main data source is a table with close to 50 million rows of data. For weeks I've been running the query in question and it's been completing in about 20 minutes. I tried running it recently and it is unusable. It takes more than 2.5 hours just to produce the first 1,000 rows of output.

Below is code from the query. What I've noticed is that when I remove the 'where' and 'having' statements and the 'sum' the query runs quickly again. Obviously this is not a solution though.

```
select YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT, sum(AGE_01_REVENUE) REVENUE
from dbo.VW_PRODUCTS
where YEAR='2015'
group by YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT
having sum(AGE_01_REVENUE) <> 0
```

Comment: Can you post an execution plan? Do you have any indexes on the table?

Comment: Does the query plan tell you anything useful, such as any suggested indexes?

Comment: Is your year really a char? Maybe there's conversion happening causing problems.

Comment: What is the data type of YEAR? Does the VW_PRODUCTS view compute the YEAR column by doing something like `YEAR(order_date) AS [YEAR]` if so, that's killing your performance. Why is the query taking so long? Grab a copy of `sp_whoisactive` and repeatedly run that while you have the above query running? Are you blocked by something? What is your wait type. And yes, actual query plan

Comment: I think the query inside the view is going to be more useful than what you've shown.

Comment: I looked at the execution plan and added indexes based on where the query seemed to be hitting bottlenecks (before posing this question). Also, yes YEAR is indeed a char (varchar(4)). YEAR is pulled straight from the original table, no computation or conversion.

Comment: @MattDionis You should post the execution plan and show us what indexes you have.

Answer (score 1):

Without an execution plan and indexes it's difficult to provide a great answer.

You could try to break down the query in to multiple steps using a temp table so the aggregation is done on a smaller dataset, something like the below.

First create a temp table with `2015` records:

```
SELECT YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT, AGE_01_REVENUE
INTO #TEMP_WORKING_TABLE
FROM dbo.VW_PRODUCTS
WHERE YEAR='2015'
```

Next, perform your aggregation on this reduced set of rows:

```
SELECT YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT, SUM(AGE_01_REVENUE) REVENUE
FROM #TEMP_WORKING_TABLE
GROUP BY YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT
HAVING SUM(AGE_01_REVENUE) > 0

DROP TABLE #TEMP_WORKING_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to look at when something is suddenly slower is out-of-date statistics.

I am wondering if this query might be faster as you only have to calculate the sum from a smaller data set.

```
select YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT, sum(AGE_01_REVENUE) REVENUE
From
(select YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT, AGE_01_REVENUE
from dbo.VW_PRODUCTS
where YEAR='2015')a
group by YEAR, BUSINESS_GROUP, STATE, PRODUCT
having sum(AGE_01_REVENUE) <> 0
```